# What happens if a user exits the browser or changes page before an AJAX request is over

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bash, shell

I am calling a php script over ajax to do some database maintenance. If the user closes the page, hits back, or clicks a link, will the php script be fully executed? Is there a way to do it?

Maybe if the php script called the `exec()` method or something similar, which would in turn call a script via the console as such:

```
$ php /var/www/httpdocs/maintenance.php
```

?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As long as the user agent (browser, etc.) has fully sent the request, the server has all it needs and will complete the request and try to send back a response.

In fact, this sort of "pinging" behavior is often used for "heartbeat"-like processes that keep a service warm or perform periodic maintenance.

Answer (score 17):

It's a race condition. PHP will detect at some point (usually upon attempting to do output) that Apache is yelling in its face that the remote user has closed the connection. Whether everything you wanted to do is done at that point depends on how your code's structured.

If you want to ensure that all operations are complete before the script shuts itself down, use [`ignore_user_abort(TRUE)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php), which keeps PHP running after the connection is severed. It's still subject to the user max_execution_time limits and whatnot, but it will not shut down because you disconnected.

Comment: So a PHP script could halt before it's execution has finished if Apache detects that the remote connection has closed?

Comment: Hahaha, I found that function right after posting, tried to cancel my question and answer it myself, but I don't have a high enough reputation yet. Here's what I wanted to write, sorry for making everybody losing time with searching the wrong thing:
**
Ok, still don't know about what exactly happens to AJAX, but I found a way to prevent PHP scripts from terminating if user interrupts the php script with the function:
ignore_user_abort()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

I should have made my research over PHP from the beginning instead of AJAX, I found it right away.
**

Comment: Could, but doesn't have to. there's other factors in play, but theoretically yes, a user could (e.g.) totally hose an ecommerce checkout process by hitting ESC after the store's inventory is updated but before the payment's been processed.

Comment: ajax requests are just an HTTP request like any other, except they're done in the background via scripts instead of explicit user actions.

Answer (score 4):

Once the web request makes it to your server, it really doesn't matter if the user closes their browser or navigates away. Your server will still respond, but no one will be listening for the response.

Comment: is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @SushantBajracharya You could use a variable that is set to "1" when the call is made, and if the user tries to redirect while the variable is "1" they get a message telling them they can't. When the call is done, it then goes back to "0" and allows redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Varies on the settings, web server, operating system and so on.

Usually the request will be processed as usual, and the response will just never be read. Occasionally, a write might fail earlier, and the request fails while processing.

Answer (score 0):

Once the ajax call is kicked off, the user is free to do whatever they want. If they close the page they simply won't get the feedback (if any ) from the ajax call that was made.

Answer (score 0):

If the php starts executing then it will continue to execute regardless if the user closes the window or navigates away from the page.

Answer (score 0):

The php script will complete, regardless of browser state.  The php is parsed on the server, and that doesn't care about whether the client is still open or not.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTTP request was completed, then yes, the PHP script will be executed fully even if the client's computer is closed.